# Одновременное использование верхнего и нижнего индексов

Tags: html, css

Предположим, мне надо записать что-то с подписями в верхнем и нижнем индексе, - уравнение электронного баланса некой реакции в блог выложить, к примеру. Можно, конечно, написать так:

```
2NO
<sub>3</sub>
<sup>-</sup>
```

Но, ожидаемо, браузер расположит текст в порядке написания, а не на одной линии, так что получится вот такая картина:

[image]

Есть ли способ в html/css расположить верхний и нижний индексы на одной линии по вертикали? Очевидное решение -- отрицательный отступ, но это костыль, к тому же -- весьма ненадёжный: Изменение шрифта может привести к тому, что индекс "поплывёт" и наложится на основной текст.

Comment: непонятно что именно не нравится. http://jsfiddle.net/aLqLu/

[так что-ли надо](http://jsfiddle.net/aLqLu/1/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант А** *(в качестве бонуса: sup и sub не увеличивают высоту строки)*
**[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/6ARre/4/).**

[image: Вариант А]

**html**

```
<span class="formula">O<span><sup>0</sup><sub>2</sub></span></span>
```

**css**

```
.formula span{
    display: inline-block;
}
.formula span sup, .formula span sub {
    display: block;
    font-size: 65%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.formula span sup {
    top: -0.6em;
}
.formula span sub {
    top: 0.4em;
}
```

---

**Вариант Б** *(sup и sub увеличивают высоту строки)*
**[Рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/6ARre/5/).**

[image: Вариант Б]

**html**

```
<span class="formula">O<span><sup>0</sup><sub>2</sub></span></span>
```

**css**

```
.formula span{
    display: inline-block;
}
.formula span sup, .formula span sub {
    display: block;
    font-size: 75%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Жаль, нет более элегантного решения, но спасибо. Я бы попробовал использовать тег [ruby][1], но его до сих пор не поддерживают Opera и Firefox.


  [1]: http://htmlbook.ru/html/ruby

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону MathML, но поддержка браузерами тоже ограничена.

Comment: @Risto, я обновил и расширил свой ответ. Теперь решение лучше работает с несколькими строками.

Comment: @Павел Азанов, он включён в HTML5, что вселяет некоторую надежду. Но пока -- увы, да.

@VenZell спасибо.